# How to access 'this' in http request's response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, this

I'm working on Alexa skill and using Node.js for writing my lambda function. I'm also using **Alexa SDK** for handling Alexa's requests and response.
The issue i'm facing is that i'm unable to access **"this pointer"** in response. Code is as:

```
var handler = Alexa.CreateStateHandler();
handler['hi'] = function( ) {

console.log("hi intent");

    request(url, function (error, response, body) {

       const message = "Hello there. Best of luck!";
       const reprompt = "Hello there.";

       this.response.speak(message).listen(reprompt);
       this.emit(':responseReady');
    });        
};
```

Error: **this.response not found**

FYI: handler['hi'] is a *listener* and is invoked automatically from Alexa. I can access this pointer outside request block.

I read different answers on SO, but none of them is answering my question. Please help, how can i access "this" inside response.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: Why are you using `this.response` (a property access) when `response` is a plain variable in your scope? But yeah, it's unclear what `reprompt` and `this.emit` are supposed to be.

Comment: @Bergi, this (this.emit, this.response) is alexa-sdk thing.

Comment: So couldn't you just use `handler.emit` and `handler.response`? Assuming `this === handler` in the `hi` method.

Comment: try to replace `console.log("hi intent")` with  `console.log(this)`, if the `this` logged is the one with `response` and `emit` you can `.bind` your callback, and then you can do request(url, callBackBinded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is really a javascript question.  The js 'this' is different then you might be used to from languages like c/c++, and the problem you are encountering here - accessing 'this' from within a callback - is a common js pitfall so it has already been answered quite well, eg.

[How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)